# How to set value programmatically for mobile number module's field using entity wrappers?

Tags: entities

how do I set value for the mobile_number field using entity wrappers?
Currently, this field is attached to an entity and I'm trying as below.

$entity_type = 'mp_customer';
$entity = entity_create($entity_type, array('type' => 'mp_customer'));
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
$wrapper->field_phone = "0777123456";

This gives an PDO Exception .... field_phone_value cannot be null....

Adding more
This field needs more data to store in field_data_field_phone,
those are:
{field_phone_value}
{field_phone_country}
{field_phone_local_number}
{field_phone_verified}
{field_phone_tfa}

This field was created using this module : https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_number

Comment: Hi @Mahinda, Please do not leave your question with no answer accepted if you want others keep helping you. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own solution. Whatever you do, just do not abandon your questions as next time less people want to react when you ask help.

Comment: Hi there,
Inserting values as an array didn't work. It throws an error as invalid data.  
So, I'm still looking for a solution save values using entity wrappers. Because using entity_save() is not actual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a value with entity wrapper `set()` should be used. Please read https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers

So your code `$wrapper->field_phone = "0777123456";` would be `$wrapper->field_phone->set('0777123456');` if the field structure required just a simple string.

However, according to the error message, it is not a string as it requires additional values for `{field_phone_value} {field_phone_country} {field_phone_local_number} {field_phone_verified} {field_phone_tfa}`.

So to make sure I would first figure out its structure. You could do so, for example, saving any value via UI and then outputting the value of respecting variable using dpm(). However, most probably its an array and you could give a try to:

```
$phone = array(
  'field_phone_value' => '0777123456',
  'field_phone_country' => 'US',
  'field_phone_local_number' => 'some value',
  'field_phone_verified' => 'some value',
  'field_phone_tfa' => 'some value'
);
$wrapper->field_phone->set($phone);
```

Comment: It's not working, 
PDO Exception error throw with 
INSET INTO {field_data_field_phone}
{entity_type}{entity_id}{revision_id}{bundle}{delta}{field_phone_value}{field_phone_country}{field_phone_local_number}{field_phone_verified}{field_phone_tfa} 
VALUES();

field_phone_value
field_phone_country
field_phone_local_number
field_phone_verified
field_phone_tfa

saying these values are NULL

Comment: Check the edited answer.

Comment: Finally, I figured out save this using entity_save()...
But entity wrappers are not working..invalid data format.

Comment: Because as I tried explain above, your are feeding just a string instead of array. Read the edited answer.